# Determining the automorphism group of the splitting field for $x^4-2x^2-\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

Let $L$ be the splitting field of $x^4-2x^2-\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q(\sqrt2)}[x]$.

Definition:
A $K$-automorphism $\sigma:L \rightarrow L$ is a morphism such that $\sigma_{|K}=\text{id}_K$, where $K \leq L$ are fields.

How do I determine the automorphism group of $L$ fixing $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$?

My attempt:

The solutions to the equations are:

$\alpha_1=\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}$

$\alpha_2=-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}$

$\alpha_3=-i\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}$

$\alpha_4=i\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}$

As far as I did understand, for a map $\sigma:L \rightarrow L$ to be a $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$-Automorphisms we need that $\sigma_{|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)}$=id

This means that the only mappings possible are permutations of $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4)$

This means that there exist $4!=24$ Automorphisms.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: There are only $2$ automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, namely the identity and $\sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}$. You might want to clarify what you are asking for.

Comment: @durianice I did edit the question

Comment: I see your update, but it doesn't make sense. An automorphism is a homomorphism from a field to _itself_. If $L\to\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is an automorphism, then $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, which is not the case.

Comment: In this case, there is no homomorphism from $L$ to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ either. A field homomorphism is always injective, but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a finite dimensional sub-space properly contained inside $L$. There cannot be a field homomorphism from $L$ to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: @durianice I did add the Definition I use of K-Automorphism. In this case $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)=K$

Comment: Ok, so you are asking for the automorphism group of $L$ fixing $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Then you should change "from the splitting field $L$ to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$". That's confusing. Because the map is not from $L$ to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Also, there's a typo on the first line.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope now everything is clear

Comment: You still say "As far as I did understand, for a map $\sigma:L \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ to be a $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$-Automorphism" You want $L\to L$ in there.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you, I edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are $24$ permutations of the roots,
not all permutations induce an automorphism fixing $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.
If so, then the automorphism group of any separable splitting field would simply be $S_n$.

For example, consider the cyclic permutation $(\alpha,-\alpha,\beta)$.
This cannot induce an automorphism $\sigma$ fixing $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.
If that were to be the case, then the following relation
$$
\alpha+(-\alpha)=0
$$
would become
$$
\begin{align*}
\sigma(\alpha)+\sigma(-\alpha) &=\sigma(0) \\
-\alpha+\beta &= 0
\end{align*}
$$
which is false.
This happens when the roots have some "unexpected" symmetry among one another (in this case if $\alpha$ is a root, then $-\alpha$ is a root).

---

First, your $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are calculated incorrectly.$\newcommand{\rat}{\mathbb{Q}}$
The four roots should be
$$
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}} \\
\beta  &= i\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}
\end{align*}
$$
and $-\alpha, -\beta$.
Then the splitting field is $L=\rat(\alpha,\beta)$.
Note that $\alpha\beta=i2^{1/4}$,
so $L=\rat(\alpha,i2^{1/4})$.

Now, $\rat(\alpha)\subset\mathbb{R}$,
so $\rat(\alpha)\ne L$
and $[L:\rat(\alpha)]\ge 2$.
Also, the quadratic polynomial $x^2+\sqrt{2}\in\rat(\alpha)[x]$ vanishes $i{2^{1/4}}$,
so $[L:\rat(\alpha)]=2$.
This shows that $[L:\rat(\sqrt{2})]=2\cdot 4=8$.$\newcommand{\g}{\gamma}\newcommand{\a}{\alpha}$

Let $\g=i2^{1/4}$.
Let $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(L/\rat(\sqrt{2}))$.
Then $\sigma$ is completely determined by its images of $\a$ and $\g$.
The automorphism $\sigma$ must map each element to its conjugate over $\rat(\sqrt{2})$.
The $\rat(\sqrt{2})$-conjugates of $\a$ are $\a, -\a, \g/\a, -\g/\a$,
and $\rat(\sqrt{2})$-conjugates of $\g$ are $\g,-\g$.
The $8$ automorphisms induced by them account for all $8$ elements in $\text{Aut}(L/\rat(\sqrt{2}))$.$\newcommand{\u}{\mu}\newcommand{\t}{\tau}$

Let $\u$ be the automorphism induced by $\a\mapsto \g/\a$ and $\g\mapsto -\g$.
Let $\t$ be the automorphism induced by
$\a\mapsto\a$ and $\g\mapsto -\g$.
We have the following multiplication table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
& \text{id} & \u & \u^2 & \u^3 & \t & \t\u & \t\u^2 & \t\u^3\\
\hline
\a & \a & \g/\a & -\a & -\g/\a & \a & -\g/\a & -\a & \g/\a \\
\g & \g & -\g & \g & -\g & -\g & \g & -\g & \g
\end{array}
$$
We see that $\u$ has order $4$ and $\t$ has order $2$,
and $\u\t=\t\u^{-1}$.
Thus, $\text{Aut}(L/\rat(\sqrt{2}))\cong D_8$,
the dihedral group of order $8$.

Comment: First, thank you for your detailed answer, it helped me a lot. But I still have a question. You did mention that "The automorphism $\sigma$ must map each element to its conjugate over $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt2)}$". I don't see why. Respectively, I don't understand why not all 24 permutations induce an automorphism.

Comment: @wanymose Updated the first paragraph to explain why not all permutations induce an automorphism. It can be confusing first time learning. Hope it helps.

Comment: @wanymose Consider an automorphism $\sigma$ of $K$ fixing a field $F$. Let $\alpha\in K$. Let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$. Note that the coefficients of $f$ are in $F$, so they are fixed by $\sigma$. This means that $0=\sigma(0)=\sigma(f(\alpha))=f(\sigma(\alpha))$, which shows that $\sigma(\alpha)$ must be a conjugate of $\alpha$.

Comment: @duriance Thank you very very much! Now I understand it.